# Call WCF service from classic ASP

Tags: wcf, asp-classic

I'm having problems calling a method in a WCF service from classic ASP. Below is the code for the service and the configuration:

**Service**

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://Plumtree.dartKW.PdfGenerator.Web")]
public interface IPdfGeneratorService
{
    [OperationContract]
    String GeneratePdf(String xml);
}

public class PdfGeneratorService : IPdfGeneratorService
{
    #region IPdfGeneratorService Members

    public String GeneratePdf(String xml)
    {
        return "hello";
    }

    #endregion
}
```

**Configuration**

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_PdfGenerator"
               maxBufferSize="2147483647"
               maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
               maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
               transferMode="Buffered">
        <readerQuotas
          maxArrayLength="2147483647"
          maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
          maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
          maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"
          maxDepth="32" />
      </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <services>
    <service behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehavior"
             name="Plumtree.dartKW.PdfGenerator.Web.PdfGeneratorService">
      <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingName="BasicHttpBinding_PdfGenerator"
                contract="Plumtree.dartKW.PdfGenerator.Web.IPdfGeneratorService" />
      <endpoint address="mex"
                binding="mexHttpBinding"
                contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    </service>
  </services>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="serviceBehavior">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

I have tested the above method in the WCF Test Client and it works fine. Here is the code from my asp page:

```
mexMonikerString = "service:mexAddress='http://localhost:51997/PdfGeneratorService.svc/mex'"
mexMonikerString = mexMonikerString + ", address='http://localhost:51997/PdfGeneratorService.svc'"
mexMonikerString = mexMonikerString + ", binding=basicHttpBinding"
mexMonikerString = mexMonikerString + ", bindingNamespace='http://tempuri.org/'"
mexMonikerString = mexMonikerString + ", contract=IPdfGeneratorService"
mexMonikerString = mexMonikerString + ", contractNamespace='http://Plumtree.dartKW.PdfGenerator.Web'"

dim service
service = GetObject(mexMonikerString)
```

Whenever I try this I get the following error:

> System.ServiceModel error '800401e4'
>
> The contract does not have an endpoint supporting the binding specified.

I've tried passing the binding configuration name `BasicHttpBinding_PdfGenerator` in the moniker instead of `basicHttpBinding` but I get the same error. I can't find any other examples of this error online either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using JavaScript without too much difficulty. Here's a copy of some JavaScript embedded in a simple HTML page that I give to my would-be WCF web service users.

The hard part might be figuring out what the WCF service expects in the request. If you have access to the WCF service code it's pretty easy to figure out. Another way would be to use Fiddler to capture successful messages sent between a client and wcf host. Or the WSDL, if you can generate one.

Good luck.

```
function Ping() {             
//set up varable
var sContent;
// 'Content-Type: text/xml \r\n ' +
// 'Host: localhost:8085 \r\n \r\n  ';
sContent=  "<xml>Your message matching the web service's data or message contract</xml>";

var xmlhttp =  new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open('POST', Demo.URL.value, true);  
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
//this section acts as a listener, waiting for response from host
if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4||xmlhttp.readyState == 0) {
    //alert("Ready state: " + xmlhttp.readyState.toString());
    if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        //alert("good");
        Demo.pingresponse.value = "Response: " +xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
    if (xmlhttp.status !=200){
        //alert("bad");
        Demo.pingresponse.value = "Error: " +xmlhttp.status.toString() +"  response text:  " +xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
} else {
    //alert("readystate bad");
}
 }
 //send request    

xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("POST http:localhost:8085/HostInterface/HostConnect HTTP/1.1"); 
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("VsDebuggerCausalityData",""); 
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader   ("SOAPAction","\"http://somestuff\""); 
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Host","localhost:8085"); 
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Expect","100-continue"); 
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Accept-Encoding","gzip, deflate"); 
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection","Keep-Alive"); 
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Length","639");                   
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8"); 
xmlhttp.send(sContent);                  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. According to countless online demos I've read my original code SHOULD work. There is a problem somewhere with either the configuration of the service or the moniker I'm constructing. There's loads of examples of people doing what I'm trying to do, unfortunately there doesn't seem to be anyone who's encountered the same error as me! Very frustrating

Comment: Understood .. I guess if you can't get your ASP version to work, you can try what I'm doing. It slots pretty easily into any HTML/ASP type construct.